# read a big text file and copy the selected lines to another file

Tags: php, file, text, fopen

I need to create a database table from [here](http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/oui.txt):

So, I copied the same file to a server folder using curl command. I need to retrieve `00-00-00   (hex) XEROX CORPORATION,  00-00-01 (hex) XEROX CORPORATION` etc. from the above text file. I need to copy only the hex values and the first line of organisation to another text file.

How can I do it with PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  <?php
  // open the input and the output
  $fp = fopen("http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/oui.txt","r");
  $out = fopen("somefile.txt","w");

  while($rec = fgets($fp)){
      // check to see if the line contains '(hex)'
      if (strpos($rec, '(hex)') !== false){
          // if so write it out
          fputs($out, $rec."\n");              
      }
  }
  fclose($fp); 
  fclose($out);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
<?php
        $i          = 1;
        $a_line     = "";
        $first_line = "";
        $handle     = @fopen("/tmp/inputfile.txt", "r");

        if ($handle) {
            while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {

                if($i == 1)
                    // here you have first line
                    $first_line = $buffer;
                else {

                    // check the $buffer contains the substring (hex) and XEROX CORPORATION
                    // if it contains put it in another variable

                    $a_line .= $buffer;

                }



            }
            if (!feof($handle)) {
                echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
        // finally write the $first_line to a header file
        // then write $a_line to another file

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php   
error_reporting(0);
$fs=fopen("1.txt", "r");
$ft=fopen("2.txt", "w");

if ($fs==NULL)
{
    echo "Can't Open Source File ...";
    exit(0);
}
if ($ft==NULL)
{
    echo "Can't Open Destination File ...";
    fclose ($fs);
    exit(1);
}

else
{
    while ($ch=fgets($fs))
        fputs($ft, $ch);

    fclose ($fs);
    fclose ($ft);
}
```

?>